# Blazor server side app with http2 enabled results in exception for certain clients

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, http2

When switching to http2 we have certain clients fail which work flawlessly using http1.1 on our Blazor Server app hosted in Azure as App Service.

```
IOException: The response ended prematurely while waiting for the next frame from the server.
o    System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.<ReadFrameAsync>g__ThrowMissingFrame|69_1()
o    System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(bool initialFrame)
o    System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()o    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
o    System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()
```

I'm at a loss what could cause this. Especially as it works for some clients/users but not for others.

Also I do not understand what the comment on the setting implies:

> When selecting HTTP version 2.0, incoming client certificates must be ignored.

Is this something we need to handle or should this be done by Blazor?

thx

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is a Transient issue on the Client and Azure App Service side, Try to Re-deploy your Blazor App in Azure App service again and check if the issue persists.

HTTP/2 is a significant modification to HTTP/1.1 that improves online speed by reducing response time. To improve user experience, HTTP/2 keeps the familiar HTTP methods, status codes, and semantics of HTTP/1.1. ***Despite the fact that HTTP/2 is designed to work with both HTTP and HTTPS, many client web browsers only support HTTP/2 via Transport Layer Security (TLS).***  Check this [**github document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/frontdoor/front-door-http2.md) to understand more about Http 2.0 a supported Browser versions for Http 2.0.

Also, Below error:-

```
 "When selecting HTTP version 2.0, incoming client certificates must be ignored,"
```

means that the client certificates are not utilised for authentication when HTTP/2 is enabled. This is something you must address in your application code. Some clients may be incompatible with HTTP/2 and are causing the problem. You can disable HTTP/2 to check if the problem goes away.

*I tried Deploying one **`Blazor Web app in Azure Web app`** and **`enabled HTTP 2.0 I was able to browse it successfully`**, Refer below:-*

[image]

*Enabled Http version 2.0 in Configuration setting like below:-*

[image]

*I was able to browse the Blazor app successfuly like below after enabling Http version 2.0.*

[image]

**My Azure Web app:-**

[image]

**Browser - Edge - 118.0.2088.61 (Official build) (64-bit)**
**Client OS- Windows**

Also, Check if you are not having any corporate or Firewall restrictions in using HTTP 2.0 for your web app.

In order to resolve this error, You can visit > **`Diagnose and solve problems`** Tab and find insights on this error code:-

[image]